# Paggination on api data in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, dart

```
 List connectProfile = [];
 connectProfile = response['data']['other_profile_verified'];

GridView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  gridDelegate:
                                      const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2.2,
                                    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                                    mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                                    crossAxisCount: 1,
                                  ),
                                  itemCount: connectProfile.length,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return displayCardConatiner(
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                        connectProfile[index],
                                        index);
                                    // ProfileCard(
                                    //   item: connectProfile[index],
                                    // );
                                  }),
```

i get data(Array) from API like this,how can i apply infinite pagination on this data.
first time only 10 data display , after that user reach to last profile ,next 10 data will be display.
how want to apply pagination on grid view.

Comment: Please add some code at least the appearance of your `Json` data or any other data source to be helped

Comment: i get data in array format and i saved that array in list

Answer (score 0):

You can use scroll listener to listen when scroll is on about the end

```
    late ScrollController _scrollController;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        // initialize scroll listener
        _scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(_initScrollListener);
      }

// init scroll listener
  void _initScrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.position.extentAfter < 500) {
      // load more more items from api and then add it to listview by using
      // code list.addAll(newItems)
      
    }
  }
```

Apply scroll controller on gridview builder

```
GridView.builder(
controller: _scrollController
)
```